# Visiting Website in VB

Tags: vb.net, html

I'm trying to get VB to 'visit' a webpage without the user knowing.  The website just has to load, no further actions are required.  Is there anyway of doing this without using a web browser?

Comment: Use a `WebBrowser` if you want to emulate a web browser; it can be hidden. Or you could hide the window of an actual web browser. What does “visit” mean, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont want to have a browser opened, you would have to just fire a Request. This maybe helps you to accomplish it:

msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/debx8sh9.aspx

This would open the page in the default browser:

```
Dim adr As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
Process.Start(adr)
```

Comment: This opens the default browser and the question asked for a solution that doesn't use a web browser. So instead propose some code that loads a page and returns the contents. That would seem an appropriate answer.

Comment: Exactly. Rewrite your answer to use this instead.

Comment: No, I want it to show as visited, without visiting at all, I already did it, no thanks to you guys

Comment: "show as visited, without visiting at all?" + "I already did it" = Fine, closed for me :)